# Can a supernova be reconciled as a creation event by. "Young Earth" religious groups and equally supported scientifically?

Tags: creation

First of all, my question is not searching for a solution to the speed of light/time issue.
ie [How do young earth creationists reconcile the age of the universe with the speed of light, and visible distant objects?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2932/how-do-young-earth-creationists-reconcile-the-age-of-the-universe-with-the-speed)

That is a different question. I do not accept that any of the answers in that question address this one.

I am looking specifically at the supernova event itself.

Theologically and Scientifically, can a supernova explain the manner in which God creates?

My understanding is that supernovas are often looked upon as being a very problematic issue with christians in that they seem to support the idea of a universe that is billions of years old and at odds with a christian claim that its only 6k years old.

I personally think both of the above views are errant...i believe the earth is 6k years old but i do not agree that the entire universe is that age. God has always existed...he has no beginning, how then could the universe have one?

So, starting with the following

Genesis 1:1 "In the beginning God created the heavens and the earth"

Genesis 1:3 " and God said, let there be light"

Genesis 1:4 "let there be an expanse..."

My understanding is that evolutionists, secular scientists, Theistic evolutionists, and creationists all agree that everything we see around us (our reality) started from a point of singularity. Clearly the difference between the secular model and the christian model is one of "God or no God".

A stumbling block i feel that i have experienced is the debate about supernovas and the light time issue. If it is quite clearly shown that supernovas that we see now are millions of light years away from us, then the exploding event must of happened millions of years ago.

This would seem very much at odds with the claim that our universe is 6k years old.

So, I got to thinking about this and wonder...

1. Can a supernova as a creation event be reconciled scientifically (this is not a religious creation event btw).
2. Can a supernova as a creation event for other worlds (like our own) be reconciled theologically (as an ongoing religious creation event for other worlds).

What would be the relevant issues with the above 2 points (both pros and cons)?

Comment: I do not accept that the reason for closing this question and the link provided has any relevance in answering it. My question is not about the light/time issue. That is a different discussion. I wish to have this question reopened! Who ever closed this does not understand what the question is actually asking. This question is specifically whether or not one can reconcile the supernova as a creation event from both a religious and scientific viewpoint.

Comment: It looks like a duplicate to me: "If it is quite clearly shown that supernovas that we see now are millions of light years away from us, then the exploding event must of happened millions of years ago." is what the linked question is about. Please explain in more detail why this is not a duplicate.

Comment: See Morris and Whitcombe's  _The Genesis Flood_ and their section on Riemannian Geometry which predicates a universe that is only (if I remember correctly) 15 light years in diameter. And the fact that Einstein has been proved wrong by quantum entanglement and that information _does_ travel across particle structures _instantaneously_ faster than the speed of light. Voted to re-open. and up-voted. Some folks have been misled by dogmatic scientists who express hypotheses as proven facts.

Comment: If light is instantaneous and it is absorption and re-emmision of photons that account for the "time delay" that produces light speed measurements then the distance to any super nova becomes irrelevant.  +1.  Also vote to reopen.

Comment: I think this Question needs to stress and explain in what ways the light from a supernova is significantly different from the light from any other star or cosmic event.  Why is it asking specifically about supernovas?  ¶ It's also not obvious what "creation event" means, as a supernova results in an existing star being destroyed and becoming a black hole or neutron star.

Comment: @NigelJ, "*While it’s one of the weirdest and coolest phenomena in physics, there is no way to use quantum entanglement to send messages faster than the speed of light.*" — [Quantum Entanglement Communication](https://quantumxc.com/blog/is-quantum-communication-faster-than-the-speed-of-light/#:~:text=The%20end%20result%20is%20always,than%20the%20speed%20of%20light.%E2%80%9D).

Comment: @NigelJ says "*Einstein has been proved wrong*".  Wrong about what?  Everything he ever said?

Comment: @RayButterworth Wrong about 'spooky interaction at a distance' as he termed it. Niels Bohr has been proved right. I did not say 'messages' : I said 'information' meaning the information that particles share. The fact is that there is a dimension to empty space and a construct to space ('field') - a medium _through which_ the energy of light travels.   And its retardation (red shift) by the medium should not be misinterpreted as movement of objects at high speed in the opposite direction.